# prepopulating admin user in database with authlogic rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authlogic, admin

I've been using the Authlogic rails plugin. Really all I am using it for is to have one admin user who can edit the site. It's not a site where people sign up accounts. I'm going to end up making the create user method restricted by an already logged in user, but of course, when I clear the DB I can't create a user, so I have to prepopulate it somehow. I tried just making a migration to put a dump of a user I created but that doesn't work and seems pretty hacky. What's the best way to handle this? It's tricky since the passwords get hashed, so I feel like I have to create one and then pull out the hashed entries...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails 2.3.4 adds a new feature to seed databases.

You can add in your seed in db/seed.rb file:

```
User.create(:username => "admin", :password => "notthis", :password_confirmation => "notthis", :email => "admin@example.com")
```

Then insert it with:

```
rake db:seed
```

for production or test

```
RAILS_ENV="production" rake db:seed  
RAILS_ENV="test" rake db:seed
```

My favorite feature in 2.3.4 so far

Answer (score 6):

If you are using >= Rails 2.3.4 the new features include a db/seeds.rb file. This is now the default file for seeding data.

In there you can simple use your models like `User.create(:login=>"admin", :etc => :etc)` to create your data.

With this approach `rake db:setup` will also seed the data as will `rake db:seed` if you already have the DB.

In older projects I've sometimes used a fixture (remeber to change the password straight away) with something like users.yml:

```
admin:
  id: 1
  email: admin@domain.com
  login: admin
  crypted_password: a4a4e4809f0a285e76bb6b35f97c9323e912adca
  salt: 7e8455432de1ab5f3fE0e724b1e71500a29ab5ca
  created_at: <%= Time.now.to_s :db %>
  updated_at: <%= Time.now.to_s :db %>

rake db:fixtures:load FIXTURES=users
```

Or finally as the other guys have said you have the rake task option, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Most used approach is to have a rake task that is run after deployment to host with empty database.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rake task:

```
  # Add whatever fields you validate in user model
  # for me only username and password
  desc  'Add Admin: rake add_admin username=some_admin password=some_pass'
  task :add_admin => :environment do
    User.create!(:username=> ENV["username"], :password=> ENV["password"],:password_confirmation => ENV["password"])
  end
```